# flex vs jsp which is better to use for creating a web portal involving cricket

Tags: jsp, apache-flex, web, flex4, project

I am really in a fix about how I should start my project. This is my first project and I thought I should start by picking a language . so can anyone guide me through that.Also which is the most recent language or framework that I should choose other then these two. I would appreciate if someone helps me here.I tried searching on net but i could not choose. please help me here

Comment: Starting by 'picking a language/technology' is generally considered a bad approach to start a project, esp. if you don't have any (web)development experience at all. You should first try to figure out what your requirements are (e.g. logins, blogs, forums, storage, picture galleries, videos, etc) and then research available technologies that enable you to realize those. Like Alexander suggested below, using a CMS would be just the right thing for you (I wouldn't recommend WordPress, though). Good luck!

Comment: To be honest I am trying to build a fantasy league of cricket and I have a deadline of december this year so I do have time. So i may learn up a new language too.And i know that CMS won't be able to do that for me . So what would you suggest?

Comment: Pick Drupal CMS and program custom additional stuff (and it could well be that you don't need that part) as a custom Drupal module in PHP.

Comment: Use JSP for the HTML generation, and Flex for the Flash generation (if you want Flash).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to program anything.

Install **Wordpress** or **Drupal** or any other CMS, configure it, add a cricket logo and off you go.

Check out this [free hosting site](http://www.drupalgardens.com) and buy your cricket logo at [a photo stock site](http://fotolia.de).

You can even find some [public domain](http://openclipart.org/detail/77947/cricket_03-by-inky2010) graphic assets if you search around:

[image: cricket (c) inky2010]

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the research, we don't know what exactly you need. The thing is that Flex is not in the same category with JSP, I think you could use both. Flex is similar more with Java applets since the code runs on the client(for Flex in a Flash player VM) and you connect Flex/Flash with you server side using whatever technology you want (so on your server you could run PHP or anything you want) . Flex offers you a large number of rich components like Tree,List,DataGrid,Charts so I would recommend this if you need this capabilities, also AS3 and the Flex Framework are OOP and is much easy to use if you are used with OOP then  HTML5(where we do not have OOP components) . The main bad part about Flex is Flash, Flash is not open and is not so "popular" . Anyway my anser is do your research.

Comment: To be honest I am trying to build a fantasy league of cricket and I have a deadline of december this year so I do have time. So i may learn up a new language too. So what would you all suggest?

Comment: @user3352106 as I and others said do the research, if you want others to tell you what to do then I suggest using Flash for the game and some PHP for the server side, if server side is more complex you can use other things(research them). Anyway your question is not respecting the guidelines of this site, and it may be flagged so do the research,read this site guidelines and ask technical questions